# Shell bash - Copiar archivos de un directorio a otro

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

> Escribe un script que reciba como argumentos exactamente dos nombres de directorios accesibles desde el directorio de trabajo actual, y que copie los archivos del primer directorio en el segundo, siempre y cuando no existan ya en el segundo directorio.

El código que he implementado es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=${*}
dire=`pwd`

if [ ${#} -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "No se han pasado dos argumentos."
    exit 1
else
    for a in ${arg}
    do
        if [ ! -d $dire/${a} ]
        then
            echo "El argumento $a no es un directorio accesible"
            exit 1
        fi
        
    done
    
    cd $dire/${1}
    str1=( $(ls -p | grep -v /) )
    cd $dire/${2}
    str2=( $(ls -p | grep -v /) )
    cont=0
    
    for i in "${str1[@]}"
    do
        for e in ${str2[@]}
        do  
            if [ ${str1[i]} == ${str2[e]} ]
            then
                cont=$((cont+1))
            fi
        done
        
        if [ $cont == 0 ]
        then
            cd $dire/${1}
            cp ${str1[i]} $dire/${2}
        fi
        cont=0
    done
fi
```

Como ejemplo tengo un directorio con 16 archivos que quiero copiar en otro directorio con un archivo que tiene el mismo nombre que uno de los archivos del primer directorio. Al ejecutar el script me copia únicamente el primer archivo del vector de archivos del primer directorio dejando el resto sin copiar.

Comment: `cp -r -n $1/* $2/`

Answer (score 0):

**Resuelto:**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare args=$*
readonly cwd="$(pwd)"

readonly src_dir="$1"
readonly dest_dir="$2"

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "No se han pasado dos argumentos."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Verificando si los directorios son accesibles"
for arg in ${args}; do
    if [ ! -d "${cwd}/${arg}" ]; then
        echo "El argumento \"$arg\" no es un directorio accesible"
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "Revisando contenido de cada directorio"
readonly content_first_dir="$(ls -p "${cwd}/${src_dir}" | grep -v /)"
readonly content_second_dir="$(ls -p "${cwd}/${dest_dir}" | grep -v /)"

echo "Copiando contenido unico"
declare -i elements_in_both=0
for element_in_first_dir in ${content_first_dir[@]}; do
    for element_in_second_dir in ${content_second_dir[@]}; do   
        [ "$element_in_first_dir" == "$element_in_second_dir" ] && ((elements_in_both++))
    done
    
    if [ "$elements_in_both" -eq 0 ]; then
        cp "${cwd}/${src_dir}/${element_in_first_dir}" "${cwd}/${dest_dir}"
    fi
    elements_in_both=0
done
```

Comment: Tu respuesta quedaría más completa si explicas como resolviste el problema y si es posible agregar algún link de documentación seria genial, recuerda que hay muchos usuarios nuevos que no comprenderán tu código si no está debidamente explicado. ;)

Comment: Traté de editar tu pregunta con nombres descriptivos y mejorar una que otra práctica. Todo para que sea más descriptivo para lectores no familiarizados.